# Dual monitor display

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a NVidia FX580. I'm using the DVI-A (analog) for the first screen. I want to hook up a second screen. The second monitor is a Samsung SyncMaster 2220WM, can  I hook this monitor up to my graphics card?

Comment: Have you tried? The FX580 clearly has several outputs.

Comment: I haven't tried. The specifications states # of digital outputs, only 2 out of 3 active at a time. I was wondering, if I can connect the Samsung syncmaster to a DisplayPort to DVI DVI-D Single Link Adapter?

Comment: Christian, the only way to know is to try it. Graphics cards don't usually have connectors that cannot be used, and their specifications are clearly detailed either on the packaging or on their online documentation.

Comment: I haven't purchased anything that can connect, my second monitor because I'm not sure, what I'm supposed to purchase

Comment: You need a cable or combination of cable(s) and adapter(s) that will go from the available ports on your graphics card to the available ports on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. you will have two screens so statement "2 of 3" is true

> Digital Outputs:  3 ( 2 out of 3 active at a time )
>
> Analog Outputs:   1

says nvidia specs. and monitor specs say:

> Input Connectors: 15-pin D-sub, DVI-D

all you need is cable